# How to Read value from the dataset(table) in SAS and make it into title of a graph?

Tags: graph, sas

I need your help please :)

I have this table which contains titles(the Countries row) for my graph
and trying to read the string values from Countries row and give that value 
into macro variable of SAS code below.

but couldn't find method for reading value of table directly.
any idea? thanks.

```
%macro graphing(howmanny,title_value);
    %do i=1 %to &howmanny;


        /*title = &title_value??????*/


        PROC GPLOT data=WORK.result
        ;
            PLOT Column&i * Horizental 
        RUN;

    %end;
%mend garphing;

%graphing(1);



table "Countries"
No. Countries
1   USA
2   Republic of Korea
3   China
4   Canada
5   United Kingdom
6   Deutschland
7   Swizerland
8   Italia
9   Vitetnam


--------------Work.Result table---------------------
Horizental  Colum1  Colum2  Colum3  Colum4  Colum5  Colum6  Colum7  Colum8  Colum9
1995    100 35  55  54  25  35  54  25  35
1995    95  45  55  55  26  46  55  26  46
1995    85  62  66  69  27  54  69  27  54
1995    70  73  64  69  60  66  69  60  66
1995    60  54  56  70  30  77  70  30  77
1995    55  65  65  80  65  99  80  65  99
1995    96  65  65  80  98  88  80  98  88
1995    66  65  65  90  26  99  90  26  99
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `PROC SQL INTO` to get the corresponding Country name into a macro variable...

```
...
  %DO I = 1 %TO &HOWMANY ;
    proc sql noprint ;
      select Country into :CTRY
      from Countries 
      where No = &I ;
    quit ;

    title "&CTRY" ;

    ...
  %END ;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you don't like SQL:

```
%DO I = 1 %TO &HOWMANY ;
    data _null_ ;
        pointer = &HOWMANY ;
        set Countries point=pointer ;
        call symputx('Country',Countries) ;
        putlog "NOTE: "Countries= ;
        stop ;
    run ;

 title "&Country." ;
[...]
```